# How to pass tanh function as an argument to another function?

Tags: c++

I have a function that takes as an argument another function:

```cpp
#include <functional>
void someFunc(const std::function<float(float)> &fn);
```

How can I pass the function `tanh` as an argument of `someFunc`? When I do the following, I get the error `cannot determine which instance of overloaded function "tanh" is intended`:

```cpp
#include <cmath>
someFunc(tanh);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
someFunc(static_cast<float(*)(float)>(tanh));
```

Or declare

```
void someFunc(float(*fn)(float));
```

And assign to a variable of type `std::function<float(float)>` inside the function.

Comment: the better solution would be to "hide" tanh behind a user written function or a lambda.
you're not allowed to take the address of a standard library function outside of some exceptions.
according to the C++ standard: 
`Let F denote a standard library function ([global.functions]), a standard library static member function, or an instantiation of a standard library function template.
Unless F is designated an addressable function, the behavior of a C++ program is unspecified (possibly ill-formed) if it explicitly or implicitly attempts to form a pointer to F.`

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that there are many overloads of [`std::tanh`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/tanh).

You might want to explicitly use the `float` variant `std::tanhf`:

```
someFunc(&std::tanhf);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use a lambda to defer overload resolution until the call happens instead of trying to specify the overload to pass to the function.  That would look like

```
someFunc([](auto val){ return tanh(val); });
```

---

I used `auto` here instead of float to make the code more adaptable.  If for some reason you decide you want to use `double`s instead of `float`s nothing needs to change in the call site to get the correct behavior.